# Only show GRUB when requested

Tags: grub2

Can the GRUB be set to operate like Os X, where by it only shows when specifically requested by a start up key or command before retart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Holding down <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> after your bios logo appears makes grub menu appear if it's hidden.  To make it hidden you need to edit /etc/default/grub with your favourite editor and add the following or remove the # if already exists

```
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
```

save and quit, then run
`sudo update-grub`
(thanks for the reminder +forespiskie)

Comment: After changing any grub file you must update afterwards as well with sudo update-grub