# How to enter the terminal from the boot manager?

Tags: boot, multiple-monitors

I have been using the Twinview dual monitor setup and recently had to take my laptop with me on a trip, and I foolishly disconnected it without changing anything in nvidia-settings.

Now, I can't log into Ubuntu (wubi). I just get the purple screen with the Ubuntu logo and .... on it. The only command that does something is ctrl+alt+del (reboot).

Is there any way I can just enter into some sort of terminal right from the boot manager so that I can delete the new xorg.conf and restore the old one?

Thanks.

Comment: What happens when you try Ctrl+Alt+F1?

Comment: Nothing happened at the "Ubuntu ...." screen. Only ctrl+alt+del caused it to restart.

Comment: just wanted to note that if your GRUB (boot manager) is hidden by default, hold down shift to make it appear http://askubuntu.com/questions/118636/only-show-grub-when-requested

Answer (score 1):

Even when using Wubi, you should still be able to get to the Grub bootloader by pressing Esc after selecting Ubuntu in Windows's boot manager. Press e to edit the first menu option.

Look for the line starting with `linux` and add `text` to the end of this line. This will make your system boot into text-mode.

Finally, press Ctrl-x or F10 to boot. After a while you should see a login prompt for a terminal.

From here, log in and remove/replace xorg.conf

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. I wanted to delete the question after I posted it because I found a fix.


On windows boot loader screen, I selected Ubuntu and pressed enter. Then I pressed shift and got into ubuntu recovery options. Next, I went to root prompt and typed in 

mount -o remount,rw /

to get root access. Then I deleted xorg.conf.