# Reinstalling/Reparing ubuntu without USB

Tags: boot, uefi, bios

I screwed up yesterday by changing my BIOS settings (from UEFI to Legacy I think) and now I can't open my BIOS correctly. I then lost the access to my old Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, but got to recover it using one USB that allowed me to install Lubuntu 18.10. This distro in the other hand seems to be somewhat corrupted (constantly freezing, freezing to suspend/restart/shutdown) I would like to know how to repair and if possible reinstall ubuntu 18.04 LTS in my PC. The problem is I don't have an USB with Ubuntu and can't make a new one.

I've seem [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/484434/install-ubuntu-without-cd-and-usb-how) but I can't install the Unetbootin and I was afraid to screw even more my PC by trying rEFInd (don't even know if it is possible to install it on Lubuntu)

I am really desperate as of right now and I am sorry if this is a already answered question/easy topic. But I am tired, have a presentation in 1h and have not slept in 34h trying to fix my PC. Thank you in advance

Comment: is it a desktop?

Comment: No, this is a [Xiaomi 13 air](https://www.gearbest.com/laptops/pp_009779202275.html?wid=1433363)

Comment: when i started ubuntu.. i messed up similar to your situation.. i removed the HDD from laptop so that system will use only the BIOS and not any OS... then i several times turned on and off without HDD.. then it was Ok..

Comment: @PRATAP yes, I saw this as an option but I am very limited as of right now in terms of how to do that. I am living for 3 weeks in France for work and I literally do work to hotel every day, that's why I was looking for something that I could do by using the terminal/software.

Comment: are you not able to reach your BIOS settings? what is your laptop model number?

Comment: No, what I've read is because I am in a fast EFI mode that just passes through my BIOS. I've tried F2 (which worked previously), DEL, ESC, F12 and F7. By doing this now (after the Lubuntu installation) I can't reach Lubuntu nor the BIOS. Before Lubuntu installation I could not reach BIOS still.

Comment: are you able to boot to LUbuntu now? is it possible for you to atleast enter into grub menu? from there you may get go to BIOS settings option.. or do you have any bootable OS?

Comment: can you provide your laptop model num..

Comment: The model is exactly the one I linked above (bought in this website). I am currently using the Lubuntu. I may not be clear because I am not a native english speaker. When I power my notebook I can't access the BIOS (after I changed the UEFI/Legacy option). I go straight to Lubuntu, without any grub in between - maybe I need to install it? (but I have no idea how to do so)

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/118636/739431

Comment: Thank you very much, now I can acess the Grub. Now I could create a partition with my ISO install (let's say Ubuntu) and install it from there, right?